# Broken and/or missing animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm just now discovering blender and getting into animation nodes and they are awesome so far! Very complex and I'm still wrapping my head around it all. I'm following along with some tutorials (Shout out to Zach Hixson) but in one of the tutorials, he used a node that I do not have in 2.1.5, which is the "Bake Sound" node.

[image]

But on 2.1.5 it's not there. Is "Sound from sequence" node the new equivalent? It had some different features and I wasn't able to properly follow the tutorial as a result.

[image]

Then I was feeling a bit overwhelmed so I started reading the manual for animation nodes, but I guess its a bit out of date? Because the bake sound node was still there. Also, there were some very interesting looking examples on there that I tried to follow, for example this one

[image]

But mine doesn't have an option for any kind of output (colors or size of dots)

[image]

Are these bugs? Or have these nodes been done away with and improved in some way?

Awesome addon! I'm loving this things capabilities! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This node has been replaced by Sound Falloff and Sound Spectrum when the falloff workflow was introduced.
Your node network should look like this :

[image]
Basically AN now generates a tweakable falloff from a music file input, in real time, there is no need to bake it anymore. The falloff can then be used to achieve a great number of effect. Here we use it to scale the pegs up and down and to change their material property so they appear to be reacting to the sound waves :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I see the sound falloff node and will look for some tutorials on how to utilize it properly.

Comment: Glad it helped ! It can be cumbersome sometimes to follow AN tutorials because some nodes changed. Remember to check out the comments under the youtube videos, often times the solution will be there. I recommend you check out Chris Prenninger if you are interested : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fruLQhn4wWg&list=PLpJWHl1fB7BFX5bxrGofVS5BEj7kOBI95

Comment: Yes his tutorials are excellent! Thank you so much! I binged tutorials 1-7 yesterday of his and they were incredibly helpful!